# To prove the map $z\mapsto (\wp(z),\wp'(z))$ is holomorphic map between Riemann surface

Tags: elliptic-curves, riemann-surfaces, analytic-functions

This is a question from Silverman's book 'the arithmetic of elliptic curves', chapter Ⅵ.

If $\Lambda$ is a lattice in $\Bbb C$ the map
$$z\mapsto (\wp(z),\wp'(z))$$
is a parametrisation of the complex points of the elliptic curve
$$E:\qquad y^2=4x^3-g_2x-g_3$$
where $g_2$ and $g_3$ depend on $\Lambda$. It induces a group
isomorphism $Φ$：$\Bbb C/\Lambda\to E(\Bbb C)$ : $t\mapsto (\wp(t),\wp'(t))$ .

To show this is isomorphism as Riemann surface, the books reads **it is enough to prove $Φ$ is local analytic isomorphism** (I understand this means we can prove $Φ$ is holomorphic map).
So, we only need to check

$$Φ^*(dx/y)＝d\wp(z)/\wp'(z)＝z\tag1$$

My question
Why (1) ensures $Φ$ is holomorphic ( or local isomorphism) ?

Comment: Is this a repost? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4156599/%ce%a6-bbb-c-lambda-to-e-bbb-c-t-mapsto-wpt-wpt-is-holomorphic

Comment: I think the point is that the invariant differential provides a non-zero element of the (one-dimensional) cotangent space at each point. Hence, it suffices to check the effect of the map on the cotangent space.

Comment: @Douglas Molin  Thank you, but the completely same phrase was written in Silverman's book. What do you mean by 'check the effect of the map on cotangent space' ? Could you explain more?

Comment: The cotangent spaces are one-dimensional vector spaces, so to show that the map is a local isomorphism you need to show that the induced map on cotangent spaces is never $0$.

Comment: Here, what do you think is the definition of 'local isomorphism'  ?

Comment: That some restriction to a neighbourhood of a point yields an isomorphism onto some neighbourhood of the image of that point. But for this proof I believe one uses a characterization analogous to that local diffeomorphisms are maps whose derivatives are isomorphisms of tangent spaces. I don't have a precise statement.

Comment: Why ' Φ* is isom' implies 'Φ is local analytic isomorphism'?