# Induced map on cotangent space is isom means the map is locally analytic isomo

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Riemann surfaces.
$Φ:X→Y$ be map between them.

I want to prove or confirm the following statement,

> Suppose induced map $Φ*$ on cotangent space of $X,Y$ is isomorphic,$Φ$
> is local analytic isomorphism.

I couldn't find any references. Any references are welcome, thank you in advance.

Comment: Presumably by "map" you mean $\Phi$ is a holomorphic (rather than, e.g., continuous map).  Compare the result of local form $z\mapsto z^n$.

Comment: No, I don't assume Φ is holomorphic, Back ground is to prove Φ:C→E(C) is biholomorphic, and Φ is known to be bijective. Our goal is to prove Φ is holomorphic. The strategy is to examine the effect of Φ on cotangent spaces.

Comment: If you don't assume $\Phi$ is (at least) $C^\omega$ there is no reason why we should have $\Phi$ local analytic iso.  For example, modify the identity $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ with a $C^1$-small bump function supported on the unit disc.  Then the inverse function theorem applies and the induced map on the (real) tangent/cotangent spaces are iso, but $\Phi$ is by construction not entire.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4157211/to-prove-the-map-z-mapsto-wpz-wpz-is-holomorphic-map-between-riemann  This question is related to this one. Could you tell me your opinion? I want to prove Φ is holomorphic, but Silverman's book reads we should examine the effect on cotangent spaces. If this titled question( Induced map on cotangent space.. ) does not hold ( without assuming Φ is holomorphic), Silverman's book's approach are meaningless.

Comment: $\Phi$ is holomorphic means for every $p$ and every charts at $p,\Phi(p)$, the map $\Phi$ is a holomorphic function with respect to the charts.  For your other question that is immediately done by looking at coordinates $1,\wp,wp'$ are $\Lambda$-periodic holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}-\Lambda$ etc.  You only need to look at tangent/cotangent map for the local isomorphism part...

Comment: (cont'd)  Without $\Phi$ being holomorphic, the cotangent map $\Phi^*$ is has nonzero contributions from the other summand in the complexified cotangent bundle $T^*C\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C}=(T^*)_{1,0}\oplus(T^*)_{0,1}$ and no longer looks like $\begin{pmatrix}\Phi^*&0\\0&\overline{\Phi^*}\end{pmatrix}$ so you cannot look only at the 1-dimensional holomorphic cotangent bundle $(T^*)_{1,0}$ alone.

Comment: Could you tell me what is ωp' ? Why we consider cotangent map? I would like to know why we should look at cotangent space.